# Is objective-c's parameter [self] correletory to JavaScript's prototype?

Tags: javascript, objective-c

Just dabbling in some Objective-C and I found this statement quite intriguing:

```
self = [super init]
```

Is Objective-C's self parameter like that of JavaScript's protoype chain?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Self is *this*, the pointer to the object itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Objective-C's inheritence model is not prototype based, it has classes as blueprints for instances. Calls on self will not lead up any prototype chain.

Obj-C's self correlates better with Java's this.

Comment: How are we able to reassign self then? I guess I should of left out the chain bit in my question. I really am asking if it's how we can reassign a class's methods/properties though the prototype. If we reassign self, that does mean that we are pulling the instance returned from the super and making our child class be an instance of it?

Comment: This should give you the answer you seek: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/what-does-it-mean-when-you-assign-super.html?m=1